# Android app does not send the TestObject to parse

Tags: android, android-studio, parse-platform

I developed an app that uses some `parse` functionality and i need to develop a new project.
I performed all the necessary steps to parse and not being able to send the `TestObject`. The app does not return any error but after running the project, `TestObject` can not be viewed in the `parse`.
I downloaded the entire project right through `parse`, so it comes with all the necessary settings.
Does anyone have any ideas?

```
ParseObject testObject = new ParseObject("TestObject");
testObject.put("foo", "bar");
testObject.saveInBackground();
```

**MainActivity**

```
package com.parse.starter;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import com.parse.ParseAnalytics;
import com.parse.ParseObject;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

ParseAnalytics.trackAppOpenedInBackground(getIntent());

  ParseObject testObject = new ParseObject("TestObject");
  testObject.put("foo", "bar");
  testObject.saveInBackground();

  }

  @Override
  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
  // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
  getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
  return true;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
  // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
  // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
  // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
  int id = item.getItemId();

  //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
  if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
  return true;
  }

  return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
  }
  }
```

**strings.xml**

```
<resources>
<string name="parse_app_id">qAoCmj2HQWmgdjy32yOgQnNZyIEkcQsXFCH1CVvc</string>
<string name="parse_client_key">tCONitHRAJYckjLZeNIn7kGFsVnbXqBrZdaAU9ZT</string>

<string name="app_name">TwitterApp</string>

<string name="hello_world">Hello World!</string>
<string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
</resources>
```

[image]

[image]

First project that ok to send TestObject

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those who have the same problem, after several attempts, I managed to solve simply. Removed the app directly on the emulator and ran the project again.

It worked.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked if the save operation has thrown any exceptions? You can try:

```
testObject.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
  public void done(ParseException e) {
    if (e != null) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
});
```